# Database analysis - rows with timed entries

Tags: mysql, database, analysis

I have a MySQL Database table with all the calls made by each user. The rows looks like:

```
id  Origin Number   Destination Number  Amount  InSec   Event Time  Event Date  YYYYMM
16196   Caller XXX  Called XXX  15.1223 825 18:02:00    03/12/2011  201112
```

The table contains 11500 rows and I need to analyze the feasibility of a certain offer which has the same rate for the first 5 call minutes and then has a different rate starting from the 6th minute until the end of the call. I can’t think of any solution except checking the top callers and doing the analysis manually, but it is very time consuming. Any idea on how to solve such request?

regards

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect in output based on a couple of input rows ?

Comment: Or create a small sample database at http://sqlfiddle.com/ for us :)

Comment: Well the thing is that we have an offer which says that for the first 5 min, the same rate applies. Starting from the 6th minute, the rate is different. I expect to be able to compare the total for each caller before and after the offer to see if it is beneficiary to apply this offer.

Comment: Is the "InSec" column (the value of which is 825) the duration in second of this particular call ? You want something like select IF(InSec > 5 * 60, ( InSec - 5 * 60 ) * ( old_rate - new_rate ), 0 ) AS savings from ... ?

Comment: Hi and thank you gave for giving me a great idea. I filtered for all the calls above 5 min and then added a few columns to calculate the rate of the 5 min, then the rate of the subsequent seconds. I dont know why i had a feeling this could not be done in excel and was wondering if it could have been done using a query or business intelligence application. For the calls below 5 min, the rate remains the same. The InSec column contain the call duration in seconds

Answer (score 0):

Based on our comments, here is a formalised sql proposal to extract the gain with the newer plan :

`SELECT IF(InSec > 5 * 60, ( InSec - 5 * 60 ) * ( old_rate - new_rate ), 0 ) AS savings from ...`

Is it what you expected ?